# PHP -> AS3 if statement

Tags: php, actionscript-3

I created php and as3 code for a website login interface. Here's the PHP code:

```
<?php

    $con = mysql_connect("xxx", "xxx", "xxx");
    mysql_query($con);
    if (!$con) {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    mysql_select_db("xxx", $con) or die('no02');
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $pass = md5($_POST['pass']);
    if ($_POST['systemCall'] == "checkLogin") {
        $select = "SELECT username FROM connexion WHERE username='$username' AND pass='$pass'";
        $query = mysql_query($select);

        $counter = 1;
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
            $name = $row['username'];
            if ($name == "joe") {
                print "systemResult=joe";
            }
            $counter = $counter + 1;
        }
    }

    mysql_close($con);

?>
```

Here's the AS3 code :

```
function dataOnLoad(e: Event) //after pressing submit button 
{
    status1.selectable = false;
    status1.text = e.target.data.systemResult
    status1.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;
    if (e.target.data.systemResult == "joe") {
        MovieClip(root).gotoAndStop(3);
    } else {
        status2.text = "Doesn't work";
    }
}
```

Now, every time I press the submit button with the right username and password, I get the right `e.target.data.systemResult` into `status1.text`, but I can't figure out why the `if` statement isn't recognizing the equality between `e.target.data.systemResult` and `joe`. It always writes "Doesn't work" into `status2.text`.

Comment: Make sure there isn't any whitespace after `?>`. You can remove `?>`, it is optional.

Comment: You should read about *SQL injection* first of all.

Comment: Are you sure that the value isn't "Joe" or "JOE" ?

Comment: Indent your code properly next time. For your own sake, you won't be able to read your code at increasing complexities.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't played around in as3 in quite awhile, but based on the description of your problem, I would guess that systemResult is an object type that a strict comparison may not make a match on. Is there a toString() method that you could apply to systemResult to see if that changes your comparison results?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use urlvariables:

```
function dataLoaded(e:Event)
{
    var phpvars:URLVariables = new URLVariables(e.target.data);

    if (phpvars.systemResult == "joe")
    {
        status2.text = "Works!";
    }
}
```

and set your php loader dataFormat:

```
phploader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES;
```

Comment: You could try to trace phpvars and phpvars.systemResult and look what their output is.